# Aggregate a Data Frame Python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a data frame like this:

> col prev_col prev_table prev_tol table count
>
> C_ShipPostalCode C_PostalCode T_customers 0 T_orders 2
>
> C_ShipPostalCode C_PostalCode T_customers 2 T_orders 2
>
> C_ShipPostalCode C_PostalCode T_customers 0 T_orders 1
>
> C_ShipPostalCode C_PostalCode T_customers 0 T_orders 1
>
> C_ShipPostalCode C_PostalCode T_customers 0 T_orders 2
>
> C_ShipPostalCode C_PostalCode T_customers 0 T_orders 1
>
> C_ShipPostalCode C_PostalCode T_customers 1 T_orders 1
>
> C_SupplierID   C_UnitPrice T_products 1 T_suppliers 3
>
> C_SupplierID   C_UnitPrice T_products 2 T_suppliers 2

I want to turn this dataframe to something like below:

> col prev_col prev_table table total prev_tol count
>
> C_ShipPostalCode C_PostalCode T_customers T_orders 6 3 10
>
> C_SupplierID   C_UnitPrice T_products T_suppliers 2 3 5

As you can see I want to group by 4 columns but also want to add the prev_tol and count from the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['col','prev_col','prev_table']).agg({'prev_tol':'sum','table':['count','max'],'count':'sum'}).reset_index()
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
               col_     prev_col_  prev_table_  prev_tol_sum  count_sum  \
0  C_ShipPostalCode  C_PostalCode  T_customers             3         10   
1      C_SupplierID   C_UnitPrice   T_products             3          5   

   table_count    table_max  
0            7     T_orders  
1            2  T_suppliers
```

Comment: @Hassan.  Great I am glad that got you on the correct course. Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) this answer.